# why does this code add dummy DOM element for animating an three object along a path?

Tags: three.js, gsap

I'm trying to move objects along side a path in three.js.

I could find an example from gsap website and the code is doing something that I don't understand.

See the code below.

```
var path = [{x: 0, y: 0, z: -100}, {x: 100, y: 200, z: -200}, {x: 200, y: 200, z: -50}, {x: 240, y: 100, z: -250}];

var proxy = document.createElement("p");
console.log(proxy)
gsap.to(proxy, {
  duration: 10, 
  repeat: -1, 
  motionPath: { 
    path, // equivalent to path: path
    autoRotate: true,
    useRadians: true
  },
  onUpdate: updateMesh
});
```

It created a dummy DOM element (I guess, which is called 'proxy' here).

and animates the three mesh object following the path as below.

```
var setX = gsap.quickSetter(cube.position, "x");
var setY = gsap.quickSetter(cube.position, "y");
var setZ = gsap.quickSetter(cube.position, "z");
var setRot = gsap.quickSetter(cube.rotation, "z");

function updateMesh() {
  setX(gsap.getProperty(proxy, "x"));
  setY(gsap.getProperty(proxy, "y"));
  setZ(gsap.getProperty(proxy, "z"));
  setRot(gsap.getProperty(proxy, "rotation"));
}
```

Why does this create a dummy DOM element? which seems quite weird to me.
Is there any better way to achieve this?

The original code is in the following link.
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/ZEGxzvJ?editors=1111

Comment: I was curious about this question, so I  had a quick look at gsap.  It's basically a sort of polyfill for css animations, so I'm guessing will require an actual dom element to apply the transforms to.

Comment: @JoshGreifer GSAP is far more than a polyfill for CSS animations :) Check out [why GSAP](https://greensock.com/why-gsap/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the original creator of that pen and the post it comes from, I believe that I used a proxy element because MotionPathPlugin doesn't work with straight WebGL objects (yet). So to make use of the plugin's super handy functionality, I created a "proxy" element that is not rendered to the page and applied it to that. Then transferred the values to the WebGL object.